# Make the compiler aware of global type definition that we installed via npm @types

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, gulp-typescript

We can now [install declaration files like this.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/09/22/announcing-typescript-2-0/)

```
npm install --save @types/whatwg-fetch
```

The types install here.

```
node_modules
  @types
    whatwg-fetch
      index.d.ts
      package.json
      README.md
      types-metadata.json
    whatwg-streams
      index.d.ts 
      package.json
      README.md
      types-metadata.json
```

Among other things, the whatwg-fetch/README.md says this.

```
 * File structure: Global
 * Global values: Headers, Request, Response, fetch
```

And the [TypeScipt documentation says this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible...

Despite that, on compiling my project with TypeScript 2.0, the following errors occur:

```
aurelia-fetch-client.d.ts(17,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Request'.
aurelia-fetch-client.d.ts(17,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Response'.
aurelia-fetch-client.d.ts(68,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Headers'.
```

What do we need to do, in order to make the compiler aware of these types?

As a workaround, we've added the following to our tsconfig.json file. From the TypeScript documentation, though, this should not be necessary.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "types": [ "whatwg-fetch" ],
```

Comment: This was annoying the heck out of me as I don't like to EVER see errors and warnings.  Even though the app was running fine.  This resolved the TypeScript error, thank you!!  Also you are correct, I have no idea why it didn't pick it up as Global, whatever...